# A qusetion about the security game of Certificateless signatures

Tags: signature, provable-security, security-definition, homomorphic-signatures

Recently I read [Certificateless Public Auditing for Data Integrity in the Cloud](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6682701/) , I have a question about the security of proposed HOMOMORPHIC AUTHENTICABLE CLS. （Sec. IV）. For the Type-I Adversary, in the forgery phase, the authors said [image],

however if $${H_1}(I{D_s}) = {({P^b})^r}$$ , which means the coin shows 0. If the coin is 0, F outputs $ \bot $  , so how does this forgery $\sigma $ comes from?